# order column in DataTable before binding to grid

Tags: c#

I have this code :

```
ProductRanges_Grd.DataSource = 
    ProductRangesDt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "PROVIDER_ID", "PROVIDER_NAME");
```

can I order by PROVIDER_NAME before binding my grid how can i do this any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 // Create DataView
DataView view = myDataTable.defaultview;
// Sort by PROVIDER_ID and PROVIDER_NAME column in descending order
view.Sort = "PROVIDER_ID ASC, PROVIDER_NAME ASC";
ProductRanges_Grd.DataSource = view.ToTable();
```

Comment: +1, much better option. I need to think outside the LINQ as well :P

Answer (score 0):

```
    myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "PROVIDER_NAME ASC"; 
    ProductRanges_Grd.DataSource = myDataTable;
    ProductRanges_Grd.DataBind();
```